# Oracle - enlarge array definition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have defined custom type in Oracle db 12c.

`create or replace type integer_varray as varray (4000) of int;`

Now I realized that I need more than 4 000 records over there so I would like to extend this definition to 5 000 without loosing all data that are already in these arrays.

Is it possible? How?

EDIT: usage is like

```
create table capacities
(
  id       int generated by default as identity (START WITH 1000000) not null
  ... other fields
  capacity integer_varray                                            not null
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can  using `ALTER TYPE .. MODIFY LIMIT` with `CASCADE` option

```
ALTER TYPE integer_varray  MODIFY LIMIT 5000 CASCADE;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7e58d39b2ba08e5d21ade8fb64b1a5c5)